# Adding javascript to drupal is not recognize some jquery

Tags: javascript, session, drupal

I am trying to get this code working on drupal, but only works when I press f5, a links or forms are not working, any idea what is the problem with this code?

My objective is to kill the session when you close the tab or close the explorer. This code is a modification from this link: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/#comment-6936

```
<code>
(function($) {


var validNavigation = false;

  var dont_confirm_leave = 0; //set dont_confirm_leave to 1 when you want the user to be able to leave withou confirmation
  var leave_message = 'Do you want to exit?';

  function goodbye(e) {
    if (!validNavigation) {
      if (dont_confirm_leave!==1) {
        if(!e) e = window.event;
        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = leave_message;
        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        //return works for Chrome and Safari
        // window.open('DelLogged.php?Id=');
        return leave_message;
      }
    }
  }

   // Attach the event click for all links in the page
  $("a").click(function () {
    validNavigation = true;
    alert("Link press");
  });

  // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
  $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116){
      validNavigation = true;
      alert("F5 press");
    }
  });

  // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
  $("form").bind("submit", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
    alert("Form press");
  });
  // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
  $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
    alert("input press");
  });

window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;

})(jQuery);
</code>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors on the page?  If so, that can kill any further js on the page.

Comment: I can't see any error, and if I press f5 the script work perfect, but i can't get working other detections like "a" or "form"

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using the `(function($){}(jQuery));` closure correctly, as the brackets are not written the right way. You've written

```
 (function($) {
   ...
 })(jQuery);
```

closing the initial bracket before `(jQuery);`

Try changing this and lets see if may solve the issue :)